# Install Display Card In ProLiant DL580 Gen8 Server

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, display, graphics, nvidia

We have a ProLiant DL580 Gen8 Server and want to install Gigabyte GForce GTX 980 ti Display Card in PCIE slot, When we connect 8 pins sockets power, server could not turn on, and when power socket not connected, server starts but the graphic card could not detect in server, now my question is:

**does this server supports this graphic card? if yes, what's the problem?**

our power cable is regular cable 8 pins.

Comment: How much wattage are your power supplies?

Comment: wattage of power supply is 4x1500 w and requirement of graphic card is 300w max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by eewhite HP support should be able to help you here.

The quick specs list the following relating to HPE Graphics cards

> HPE Graphic Options
>
> NOTE: Up to five cards are supported on the DL580 Gen8. Supporting
>   multiple number of cards on the DL580 Gen8 blocks some active IO cards
>   as follows due to space constraints:
>
> For 2P config: Max of 2 double-wide cards are supported on slot 6 and
>   slot 9 (slot 8 is blocked)
>
> For 3P config: Max of 3 double-wide cards are supported on slot 3,
>   slot 6 and slot 9 (slot 5 and slot 8 are blocked)
>
> For 4P config: Max of 5 double wide cards are supported on Slot 1,
>   Slot 3, Slot 2, Slot 6 and Slot 9 (slot 5 and slot 8 are blocked).
>
> NOTE: HPE DL580/DL585/DL980 Power Cable Kit (631660-B21) is required
>   for Graphics cards. Each cable kit has two 8-pin connectors (one 150W
>   and other 225W) and can support up to two cards. For three cards, two
>   cable kits are required. For five cards, three cable kits are
>   required. The cards pull up to 75W of power from the IO slot and the
>   rest from the auxiliary power connectors.
>
> NOTE: Both UEFI mode and Legacy Mode are supported.
>
> NVIDIA Quadro K6000 PCI-E Graphics Adapter
>
> 730874-B21
>
> NOTE: Supported at Gen2 speeds
>
> NVIDIA Tesla K40C 12GB Computational Accelerator
>
> 753960-B21
>
> NOTE: Supported at Gen2 speeds
>
> NVIDIA GRID K2 Reverse Air Flow Dual GPU PCIe Graphics Accelerator
>
> 753958-B21
>
> NOTE: Only three cards are supported with MS Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> Auxiliary Power Cables
>
> NOTE: The DL580 Gen8 supports six auxiliary power connectors
>
> HP DL580/DL585/DL980 Power Cable Kit NOTE: Order with GPGPUs for
>   providing additional power to the IO cards.
>
> 631660-B21

@chicks

Sorry I should have provided a link.

For HP quick specs I usually use the Quick Specs offline utility which can be downloaded from this page

http://h71069.www7.hp.com/quickspecs/overview.html

HP PB Application link is near the bottom of page.

It will take a while to update ( depending on network connection and selected product filters) but has reasonable search facility for just about every HP product made.

OAM

Comment: It looks like you are quoting something here, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @chicks I would think http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14743_div/14743_div.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a ***"Call HP for support"*** situation.

Your DL580 Gen8 is a $15k+ server and still under warranty. What you're doing seems to be an edge case for normal usage, but HP support should be able to work this out for you.